# Why DirtiesContext is needed on other test classes to mock bean dependency for class with JMS Listener

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

**Context**

A Spring Boot application with a Rest endpoint and a JMS AMQ Listener

**Test behaviour observed**

The tests classes run fine without needing DirtiesContext individually but when the entire suite of test classes are run the following behaviours are observed -

1. Mocking of a bean dependency for the JMS Consumer test requires the earlier test classes to have a DirtiesContext annotation.
2. Mocking of bean dependency for RestControllers seem to work differently than a JMS Listener i.e don't need DirtiesContext on the earlier test classes

I've created a simple Spring application to reproduce the Spring context behaviour I need help understanding - https://github.com/ajaydivakaran/spring-dirties-context

Comment: What is the problem without `DirtiesContext`? Please add the error and the test report

Comment: When running the entire test suite in debug mode I see that for the failing JMS consumer test the actual EnergeticGreeter bean is present in the Consumer class instead of the expected mock bean.

Comment: Please add any error and the test report

Comment: The error or assertion failure is that the mock is not invoked. The absence of the mock bean injection is what I'm trying to reason about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this happens is due to the fact that without `@DirtiesContext` Spring will remain the context for reuse for other tests that share the same setup (read more on Context Caching in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching)). This is not ideal for your setup as you have a messaging listener, because now multiple Spring Contexts can remain active and *steal* the message you put into the queue using the `JmsTemplate`.

Using `@DirtiesContext` ensures to stop the application context, hence this context is not *alive* afterward and can't consume a message:

> from @DirtiesContext:
>
> Test annotation which indicates that the {@link org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext ApplicationContext}  *
> associated with a test is *dirty* and should therefore be
> closed and removed from the context cache.

For performance reasons, I would try to not make use of `@DirtiesContext` too often and rather ensure that the JMS destination is unique for each context you launch during testing. You can achieve this by outsourcing the `destination` value to a config file (`application.properties`) and randomly populate this value e.g. using a [ContextInitializer](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/tests-context-initializer.html).

A first (simple) implementation could look like the following:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class Consumer {
    private EnergeticGreeter greeter;
    private MessageRepository repository;
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @JmsListener(destination = "${consumer.destination}")
    public void consume(
            @Header(name = JmsHeaders.MESSAGE_ID, required = false) String messageId,
            TextMessage textMessage) {

        System.out.println("--- Consumed by context: " + applicationContext.toString());

        if ("Ahem hello!!".equals(greeter.welcome().getContent())) {
            repository.save();
        }
    }
}
```

the corresponding test:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = DestinationValueInitializer.class)
public class JMSConsumerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Value("${consumer.destination}")
    private String destination;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @MockBean
    private EnergeticGreeter greeter;

    @MockBean
    private MessageRepository repository;

    //Todo - To get all tests in this project to pass when entire test suite is run look at Todos added.
    @Test
    public void shouldInvokeRepositoryWhenGreetedWithASpecificMessage() {
        when(greeter.welcome()).thenReturn(new Message("Ahem hello!!"));

        System.out.println("--- Send from context: " + applicationContext.toString());

        jmsTemplate.send(destination, session -> session.createTextMessage("hello world"));

        Awaitility.await().atMost(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).untilAsserted(
                () -> verify(repository, times(1)).save()
        );
    }
}
```

and the context initializer:

```
public class DestinationValueInitializer implements
        ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        TestPropertyValues.of("consumer.destination=" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()).applyTo(applicationContext);
    }
}
```

I've provided a [small PR](https://github.com/ajaydivakaran/spring-dirties-context/pull/1) for your project where you can see this in the logs, that a different application context is consuming your message and hence you can't verify that the repository was called on the application context you write your test in.